# Alternative to multiple AND operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

is there a cleaner(better) alternative to using multiple AND operator in T-sql.

for example

```
use Portal
go
SELECT
U.Id,
U.FirstName,
U.LastName,
U.Email,
U.Gender, 
U.Country

FROM AspNetUsers U
WHERE (U.M01 >= 80 and U.M02 >= 80 and u.M03 >= 80 AND U.M04 >= 80)
```

Comment: Your logic is fine.  Nothing needs to be changed (although the parentheses are unnecessary).

Comment: You asked "how", when you should have asked "why?". Why is your data organized in such a way that you *need* to make a query like this? It may be just fine, or it might be a sign that your design has... reserves. We can't really help you with that, though. But if your design works fine (for whatever reasons are hidden to us), using four separate `and`s is entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If AND is what you need then AND is the proper operator.

AND is efficient as it can give up as soon as it gets a single false. 
The query optimizer is (typically) smart enough to look for the easy false first.

OR is not as efficient so some times you will refactor to get rid of the OR but I have never had a reason to refactor an AND.

If the value changes then maybe go with this for convenience but it should not effect execution

```
declare @count int = 80;
SELECT
U.Id,
U.FirstName,
U.LastName,
U.Email,
U.Gender, 
U.Country
FROM AspNetUsers U
WHERE U.M01 >= @count 
  and U.M02 >= @count  
  and u.M03 >= @count  
  AND U.M04 >= @count;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, if result depends on columns that you have in WHERE. If there will be good index it will be fast too (good index for this query is

```
create index [some name] on AspNetUsers (M01, M02, M03, M04) include (Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Gender, Country)
```

But this query looks strange and probably it is problem with design/normalization

Answer (score 1):

There are few options to simplify this particular selection syntax but it is hard to say if they make sense without knowing your entire context and your definition of better/cleaner...

Let's assume that cleaner/better means "selection without conjunction operators" for you.

Some of possible options:

1. Create a view that will prefilter your AspNetUsers table. Then your query syntax could be simplified to:

   SELECT
   Id,
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   Email,
   Gender, 
   Country
   FROM AspNetUsersPerfiltered
2. Move filtering logic to dedicated function that will check the condition. Then your query syntax could be simplified to:

   SELECT
   Id,
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   Email,
   Gender, 
   Country
   FROM AspNetUsers
   WHERE myFunction(M01, M02, M03, M04) = 1
3. Create additional column(flag) that will be set during row insert/update or by some background process. Then your query syntax could be simplified to:

   SELECT
   Id,
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   Email,
   Gender, 
   Country
   FROM AspNetUsers
   WHERE FlagColumn = 1

HTH